# animated GIF not working if Button is disabled

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, animated-gif

Just like what is said above, I'm having a problem regarding animated GIF. I have a **`button`** then if the button is clicked it show/display **`LOADING GIF`** within the **`button`** but I want that button not clickable while in the process of loading. So I use **`me.btn1.enabled = false`** but then the **`LOADING GIF`** is not working. What I mean is, it is visible but the **`ANIMATED LOADING GIF EFFECT`** not moving/working (or whatever you call that staff).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  You are already indicating to the user that clicking the button isn't going to have any effect.  So you don't *also* have to disable it.  Just ignore the click in your Click event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your button enabled but change the code behind so it ignores subsequent clicks if the loading process is underway. You could use a simple state flag for this.

```
Dim IsLoading As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (IsLoading) Then
        Return
    Else
        IsLoading = True
        ' Update button with loading GIF, do loading logic etc.
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, you will need to reset `IsLoading` when your load is complete.

OR, hide the button when loading and show a PictureBox containing the loading GIF in its place.

Comment: Thanks. I use the Picture box overlay button